# Can I inherit from an OCaml class chosen at runtime?

Tags: ocaml

So right now I have two classes of the same class type, e.g.

```
class foo : foo_type = object ... end

class bar : foo_type = object ... end
```

I'd like to have a third class that inherits from either `foo` or `bar` at runtime. E.g. (pseudo-syntax)

```
class baz (some_parent_class : foo_type) = object
    inherit some_parent_class
    ...
end
```

Is this possible in OCaml?

Use case: I'm using objects for constructing AST visitors, and I'd like to be able to combine these visitors based on a set of runtime criteria so that they only do one combined traversal over the AST.

Edit: I think I have found a way to create the desired class using first-class modules:

```
class type visitor_type = object end

module type VMod = sig
  class visitor : visitor_type
end

let mk_visitor m =
  let module M = (val m : VMod) in
  (module struct
    class visitor = object
      inherit M.visitor
    end
  end : VMod)
```

However, it seems a little roundabout to have to wrap a class in a module in order to make it "first-class". If there's a more straightforward way please let me know.

Comment: You can ease this a little with `let mk_visitor (module M : VMod) = ...` instead of the `let module`.

Comment: yeah I'm going to do that when the codebase I'm working on upgrades to OCaml 4. Right now we're still supporting 3.12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not contrary to what Jeffrey said, but you can achieve this using first-class modules. Also, I'm not sure that you really need to create classes on runtime, maybe creating object would be enough. If what you want to get is different behavior, then this will be enough.

Comment: See my edit -- I think I figured out how to do it using first-class modules, although it seems unfortunate that classes are not themselves first-class.

Comment: Yes, classes in OCaml are not very popular, that's why they're not first-class in both senses of that word.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a cleaner implementation of what you already suggested, but I would do it like this:

```
module type Foo = sig
  class c : object
    method x : int
  end
end

module A = struct
  class c = object method x = 4 end
end

module B = struct
  class c = object method x = 5 end
end

let condition = true

module M = (val if condition then (module A) else (module B) : Foo)

class d = object (self)
  inherit M.c
  method y = self#x + 2
end
```

Answer (score 2):

OCaml has a static type system. You can't do anything at runtime that would affect the type of something. Inheritance affects the types of things, so it can't happen at runtime.

(Your code also confuses types with values, which is understandable.)

There is probably a way to get close to what you want while retaining the desirable properties of static typing. What you actually need may be more like function composition, perhaps.

Comment: If I'm inheriting from a class with a known class type, shouldn't the type of the child class be deducible at compile time?

Comment: Inheritance happens at compile time, it's part of the definition of a class (a type). You can of course have a value at runtime that might be an instance of any subclass of some class. This is just regular OO semantics. But maybe I don't get what you're asking.

Comment: Does my edit make it clearer? My understanding is that classes and class types are distinct, and the latter has to be fixed at compile time, but not the former.

Comment: when you define class you're automatically define a type and a class type, as well as the class itself. That's why you need to pack it into the module. It can't be done other way, because classes by itself can't contain types.